# Optimise test for jest using beforeAll instead of beforeEach

Tags: javascript, angular, jestjs

I'm writing tests for checking if the parent component is getting called when child component emits some data, here is how I set up my components for testing:

```
  describe('OperationComponent', () => {
  let component: OperationComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<OperationComponent>;
  let store: Store;
  let de: DebugElement;
  let data: any;
  let cmp: any;
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    const {
      imports,
      providers
    } = configureDefaultTestingMouduleForSecureComponent(OperationComponent);
    TestBed.resetTestingModule();
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [OperationComponent],
      imports: [...imports, NgxsModule.forFeature([RoutesOperationState])],
      providers: [...providers, RoutesOperationEntity]
    }).compileComponents();
    store = TestBed.get(Store);
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(OperationComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    de = fixture.debugElement;
    data = de.query(By.directive(RouteOperationsComponent));
    cmp = data.componentInstance;
    component.routeId = mockRoutes[0].id;
  });
describe('cancel action', () => {
      it('should be called on cancelOperation when it emits data', () => {
        jest.spyOn(component, 'handleCancelRouteOperation');
        cmp.cancelRouteOperation.emit(true);
        expect(component.handleCancelRouteOperation).toHaveBeenCalledWith(true);
      });
    });
```

`configureDefaultTestingMouduleForSecureComponent()` has my shared modules and other angular modules. I want to use `beforeAll()` instead of `beforeEach()`, because using `beforeEach()` is slowing down my test suite. When I use `beforeAll()` though, my child component `RoureOperationsComponent` is not getting instantiated correctly and it throws an error.

```
expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)

    Expected: true

    Number of calls: 0
```

Comment: Please include the error you are getting.

Comment: @Erbsenkoenig I have added the error message in my question description

Comment: I guess after having a look at [this article](http://breazeal.com/blog/jasmineBefore.html), the beforeAll block gets executed before even the test setup is done, since this is inside a beforeEach and they are in the same describe block. Have you tried moving this beforeAll into your 'cancel action' describe block? Please try and reproduce the error in a stackblitz or something similar otherwise it's quite hard to help you resolving the issue.